# Type of obj argument in SerializerMethodField DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this Django REST Framework serializer class:

```
class DoctorMeetingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    doctor_id = serializers.CharField()
    patient_id = serializers.CharField()
    meetings_amount = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = DoctorMeeting
        fields = (
            'id',
            'doctor_id',
            'patient_id',
            'start_time',
            'end_time',
            'subject',
            'meetings_amount',
        )
        read_only_fields = ('zoom_meeting_id', 'is_live', 'meetings_amount',)

    def get_meetings_amount(self, obj):
        print(type(obj))
        meetings_amount = DoctorMeeting.objects.filter(patient=obj.patient_id).count()

        return meetings_amount
```

So when I do GET request, print(type(obj)) shows that obj is serializer instance, but then I do POST request, obj becomes an OrderedDict instance and has no 'patient_id' attribute. Why does this object changes its type in different request methods?

Comment: I guess issue is in your view, post your view as well in question.

Comment: yes, view could be the dilema, but you can achieve reading dict by following way. **self.__dict__['initial_data']**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `POST` request, it means you try to create new object, so the instance is `None`. And to generate data the drf used only dict, here part of the source, more details [data property](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L260) :

```
if self.instance is not None and not getattr(self, '_errors', None):
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
elif hasattr(self, '_validated_data') and not getattr(self, '_errors', None):
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.validated_data)
else:
    self._data = self.get_initial()
```

Comment: Thank you, seems you are right. But I'm wondering why does it even evaluate the body of get_meetings_amount() while doing POST request. This field is read only, it's for GET requests only.

Comment: as you see current method call another `to_representation` where loop for `self._readable_fields` -- all fields that are not `write_only`